# Android Kiip Popart is always coming null

Tags: android, ads, kiip

I am trying to integrate Kiip rewards sdk and when i am listining for the callback popart is always coming null.

```
Kiip.Callback cb = new Kiip.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailed(Kiip kiip, Exception exception) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to save moment " + momentId, exception);
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinished(Kiip kiip, Poptart poptart) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Moment saved poptart=" + poptart);
                        // WARNING: poptart may be null if no reward was given, but
                        // KiipHelper#showPoptart checks for this
                        showPoptart(poptart);
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrew from Kiip here. As noted in the comment "// WARNING: poptart may be null if no reward was given...", there will not always be a reward for each moment. Rewards are dependent on inventory for a given geo-location.

A null response means your integration is working, however there is no reward to deliver in the respective moment save.

Considering that you're receiving a null response every time, you may want to try using a VPN based in the US. Additionally, setting up for test rewards will help ensure a working intergration:
http://docs.kiip.me/en/guide/android.html#adding-yourself-as-a-test-device

Comment: does test rewards also requires US based VPN?

Comment: Good questions. Test rewards will fill 100% of the time (unless you're spamming moments) regardless of geolocation. No need to use a VPN.